# Delete an element with specific node name from XML file using XDocument and XmlDocument class

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to delete an element with specific node name. Using the following code but receive an error like "Name cannot begin with the '2' character, hexadecimal value 0x32." As I understand this method is not correct for the relevant xml format.

How can I delete Table with specific User_Name info. should delete specific table When I try to delete Administrator User

```
RemoveElement("Accounts.xml", "User", "Test1");

private static void RemoveElement(string xmlFile, string elementName, string elementAttribute)
    {
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
        foreach (var profileElement in xDocument.Descendants("Table").ToList())              
        {
            if (profileElement.Attribute(elementAttribute).Value == elementName) 
            {
                profileElement.Remove();                               
            }
        }
        xDocument.Save(xmlFile);
    }
```

Here is the Xml file;

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Accounts>
  <Table>
    <User>Administrator</User>
    <Domain>Localhost</Domain>
    <Password>Test</Password>
    <Account_Type>Windows</Account_Type>
 </Table>
 <Table>
    <User>Test1</User>
    <Domain>demo</Domain>
    <Password>empty</Password>
    <Account_Type>Domain</Account_Type>
 </Table>
</Accounts>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original code snippet doesn't work because name of user is not an attribute of user but a value. Also, you can replace `.Descendants("Table")` with `.Descendants(elementName)` to avoid unnecessary if statement.
I think, the most elegant way to achieve needed functionality is to use Linq to Xml:

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

xDocument.Descendants(elementName)
    .Where(e => e.Value == elementAttribute)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(e => e.Remove());

xDocument.Save(xmlFile);
```

As for your second question: I believe that you remove first element in this line

```
listViewMevcutKullaniciListesi.Items.RemoveAt(listViewMevcutKullaniciListesi.SelectedIndices[0]);
```

When you call `listViewMevcutKullaniciListesi.SelectedIndices[0]` for the second time you obviously get an Exception.
Also, `listViewMevcutKullaniciListesi.SelectedIndices[0].ToString()` don't give you selected item but just it's number.

Comment: Than How can I get selected item info from listview as elementAttribute

Comment: Please, try something like `listViewMevcutKullaniciListesi.SelectedItems[0].Text` *before* you remove it from ListView. I don't have access to Windows Forms project right now to test it, sorry..

Comment: Yeah I used selectedItems[0].Text you said and perfectly working. Dont be sorry. Thank you so much

Comment: Maxim can you look at my last post. There is a problem about using XDocument class. Will be apriciate if you help

Comment: You get NullReferenceException because you removing objects from IEnumerable while enumerating it. You change the sequence while enumerating this sequence. You should copy IEnumerable (by calling .ToList()) to be able to change it. So, `foreach (XElement profileElement in xDocument.Descendants(nodeName).ToList())` should work. Also, you can use `.Descendants(elementName)` instead of `.Descendants(nodeName)` to remove `profileElement.Element(elementName)`.. just check `.Value`.. Please, try my snippet with Linq to Xml. It should work fine.

Comment: you are best :). Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Found it how you can delete when you get info from texBox

```
xDoc.Load("Accounts.xml");
                foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.SelectNodes("Accounts/Table"))
                {
                    if (node.SelectSingleNode("User").InnerText == textBox1.Text)
                    {
                        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
                    }

                }
            xDoc.Save("Accounts.xml");
```

But I Want to get info from listview. I receive an error When I try to use following code.

Error : InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.\r\nParameter name: index

```
listViewMevcutKullaniciListesi.Items.RemoveAt(listViewMevcutKullaniciListesi.SelectedIndices[0]);

xDoc.Load("Accounts.xml");
                foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.SelectNodes("Accounts/Table"))
                {
                    if (node.SelectSingleNode("User").InnerText == listViewMevcutKullaniciListesi.SelectedIndices[0].ToString())
                    {
                        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
                    }

                }
            xDoc.Save("Accounts.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer with XmlDocument class;
You are calling the method like

```
`RemoveElementWithXmlDocument("Accounts.xml", "Accounts/Table", "User", listViewMevcutKullaniciListesi.SelectedItems[0].Text);`
```

method;

```
private static void RemoveElementWithXmlDocument(string xmlFile, string nodeName, string elementName, string elementAttribute)
    {
        xDoc.Load(xmlFile);
        try
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.SelectNodes(nodeName))
            {
                if (node.SelectSingleNode(elementName).InnerText == elementAttribute)
                {
                    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
                }
            }
            xDoc.Save(xmlFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And also I wanna use XDocument class for same structure But I receive an exception like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in foreach loop when the ran profileElement.Remove(); line. If I comment out to this line never get the exception but I need this line for removing relevant node from xml. So, As I understand I missing something in XDocument. need your help

```
RemoveElementWithXDocument("Accounts.xml", "Table", "User", listViewMevcutKullaniciListesi.SelectedItems[0].Text);
```

method for XDocument

```
private static void RemoveElementWithXDocument(string xmlFile, string nodeName, string elementName, string elementAttribute)
    {
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
        try
        {
            foreach (XElement profileElement in xDocument.Descendants(nodeName))
            {
                if (profileElement.Element(elementName).Value == elementAttribute)
                {
                    profileElement.Remove();
                }
            }
            xDocument.Save(xmlFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```